# How to get the data on the basis of `parent` field

Tags: mongodb, mgo

I want to make a customize menu bar according to user and After analysis of requirement I found some field for this are:- `id`, `name`,`slug`, `parent`, `description`, `order`, `taxonomy`. I also make a api which will save the data in the database with these fields. I'm using mongodb database and golang api's for this. But I stuck in one case is that:-

**Case:-** If a user add a page `HOME`, `LINKS`, `Contact-US`.
        Under the `LINKS` page there are two childs pages `link1` and `link2`. Same For `Contact-Us` page there are two childs `Contact1`, `Contact2`. Then how we will send the data into the database and how we will define that which menu page having which childs. Is there any way to do this? Below I'm defining the types of the fields:-

```
Id           int
Name         string
Slug         string
Parent       int
description  string
order        int
taxonomy     string
```

Is these Fields are sufficient for adding the `menu bar` according to the user?

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: are you using mongoose?

Comment: @AbhishekKumawat no